# Conditional static field possible?

Tags: java, static

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Level{
public int level;
public int score;
}
```

Basically, I would want to behave the score as static for a particular value of level. For example,in a competition, a team has multiple competitors, each contributes to the score for a particular level. I wish to add each of their contributions to the score whenever level is equal. 
I was wondering if it could be done this way.

**EDIT**

I feel the problem will be more easy to visualise if I change my Class a bit like this:

```
public class Participants{
public String name;
public String teamID;
public int[] levelScores; //where the level is denoted 
                            //by the index of this array
}
```

Now, for all participants with the same teamID, the levelScores must be shared and contribution of any participant object with same teamID must be added to the corresponding levelScore.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Do the classes that reference `Level` get it from somewhere known or create it themselves?

Answer (score 3):

That involves changing the code and is unlikely to be worth the extra complexity IMHO. I would just use the code you have (and make the fields final if you can)

```
abstract Level {
    public int getLevel();
    public int getScore();
}

class LevelOne extends Level {
    public int getLevel() { return 1; }
    public int getScore() { return LEVEL_ONE_SCORE; }
}

class LevelTwo extends Level {
    private final int score;
    public int getLevel() { return 2; }
    public int getScore() { return score; }
}

class LevelN extends Level {
    private final int level;
    private final int score;
    public int getLevel() { return level; }
    public int getScore() { return score; }
}
```

Comment: I think you just want `Level` (currently `LevelN`) and `LevelOne`

Comment: LevelN has a field for the score. AFAIK There would be no point having a LevelOne if it had this field as well.

Comment: Very static way of doing it. `level` isn't `final` in the example, so I would have to assume it's also mutable.

Comment: @AlanEscreet I tend to assume people leave things as non-final because they haven't thought about it. ;)  If the code is copied and works then it is better than making it non-final when it could have been final esp as it is public.

Comment: That's a fair assumption. I've made the same assumption, but with an alternative that doesn't require a recompile every time a new level is added.

Answer (score 3):

Change to using accessor methods (getters/setters) and do this:

```
class Level {
    private static int levelOneScore;
    private int level;
    private int score;

    public int getLevel (
        return level;
    );

    public int getScore() {
        return level == 1 ? levelOneScore : score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        if (level == 1) {
            levelOneScore = score;
        } else {
            this.score = score;
        }
    }
}
```

I've omitted the `setLevel()` method because it feels like level should be final. If `level` is `final`, you could (and should) implement this as a separate class that overrides the get/set score methods.

Comment: +1 I did think of this and its not as OOP but is what I am more likely to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look at your profile... you're learning by yourself, so I'm assuming that you won't use anything like JNDI, Spring or any other kind of container or framework.

The simplest way of doing this without resorting to a completely static class hierarchy is to use the `level` as a key to reference the score:

```
public class Level {
   private static Level instance = null;
   private static Map<Integer, Integer> scoreMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

   public static Level getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new Level();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public static int getScore(int level) {
      return scoreMap.get(level);
   }

   public static void setScore(int level, int score) {
      scoreMap.put(level, score);
   }
}
```

Any class that uses `Level` will do it in this way:

```
int myLevel = 1; // I assume the class will know its level somehow

Level scoreKeeper = Level.getInstance();

int myScore = scoreKeeper.getScore(myLevel);
```

This solution uses the horrible Singleton anti-pattern, but it will get you going with what you probably want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it is possible. `static` is only one copy shared across application. You need to think about re-design your code.

Answer (score 0):

STATIC DATA is shared by all the instances of the class. your level 1 instance would share it so does your levelN:).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of overhead associated with this answer, but you can create a score class that has one field `int score` and point all level objects where level = 1  at the score object. That way every time the score is changed, it is changed for all objects that point to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it the way you're thinking.
But it is possible to make a class with a single static method that returns the score to the appropriate input value.

The method:

```
    public static int(int level) {
        if(level==1) {
            return //what you want.
        }

}
```

I hope I helped.